# displaying command output on webpage using perl cgi

Tags: linux, perl, cgi

below is the code,
please give me any suggestions to display the result of the command output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings;
print "content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print <<EOF;
<html>
<head><title>command</title></head>
<body>
EOF
my $d=qx(perl -cw 1.cgi);
print <<EOF;
<p>$d</p>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Comment: `my $d=qx(perl -cw 1.cgi 2>&1);`

Comment: More about  [`2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qx` will return the `STDOUT` in variable but you are trying to store the Perl compiling result into your variable, In Linux it is called as `STDERR` not a `STDOUT` so we need to do as follow

```
my $d=qx(perl -cw 1.cgi 2>&1);
```

More about  [`2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)